# what is the best way to check performance/limitation of web application in Meteor.js?

Tags: javascript, meteor

We have built a webapp using Meteor.JS and we would like to find out

1. how will it perform in real production mode when thousands/millions of users can log request/response.
2. How efficient will be the framework when it comes to volume and response time.

We would like to know if there is any tools or best practices which we can use.

Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: Read up on "load testing"

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is look at load testing your app.  There are many ways to do this, but the premise is that you script what a user interaction consists of and you run that script multiple times, ramping up the volume until you get to the concurrency numbers you are looking for.

As mentioned, there are LOTS of tools to do this.  Some I have personally used:

- Loadrunner
- Apache jMeter
- Rational Performance Tester
- Simple shell scripts with curl

There is a list on Wikipedia that would give you a good start on what other tools may be available.

The next point I'd like to make is that load testing is not just ramping up the concurrent users until the system breaks.  A good load test will attempt to mimic the type of traffic you see or expect to see.  To say it another way, two users do not do the exact same thing each time they hit your system, and not all requests to your server produce the same load on your system.  Your users may even use the system differently at different times of the day.

The ultimate goal would be to have several "types" of users and transactions scripted, and have your load tool of choice weight the requests such that they match the expected percentages for each type.  This way you can better see how your application will perform over time with loads that match what you really expect to see.

Finally, you need to consider your infrastructure.  Typically, in the Enterprise environments I have worked in, we try to make our QA environment as close to Production as possible.  We would have the exact same server hardware, exact same configuration (both physical and software), and attempt everything possible to make it mirror.  Where we sometimes deviate is the size.  For instance, I worked in on environment where we had 4 app servers in Prod, each with 4 nodes, for a total of 16 nodes in a cluster.  In QA, we had the same bare metal hardware, but everything was cut in half, so we had 2 physical servers, each with 4 nodes totally 8 nodes in the QA cluster. When we tested for load, we would then half the expected total, so if we expected 200 users concurrently in Prod, a successful QA test would be 100 users concurrently.  We would also copy and obfuscate data from the Production databases to the QA databases to make sure we are operating with the same sized data.

The process for load testing is this:

1. Grab a "baseline" result
2. Make whatever changes you need to make
3. Rerun the EXACT same tests as #1, only adding any new functionality to your tests

The baseline is important when making changes over time to ensure that your change doesn't effect performance.  I can't tell you how many times I have seen SQL statements that ran perfectly fine in Dev that completely took down a system because of differences in the amount of data.